# Get element from array that is bigger than num, plus the next index

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an object like this:

```
const obj = {
  1: 10,
  2: 20,
  3: 30,
  4: 40,
  5: 50,
};
```

And i have a number for example: 25

Now i want to iterate over the obj with `Object.entires(obj)`, and i need the result like: 25 is bigger than the second element value: 20. So the return value should be:

`{ 2: 20 }` <- this one is working flawless, but how can i get the result like:

```
{
  current: {
    2: 20
  },
  next: {
    3: 30
  }
}
```

I also need the next value from the obj.

Comment: Use `findIndex` on your entries. And then the next is the index+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert your object into an array:

```
arr = Object.entries(obj);
```

This will return an array of key value pairs. Then, loop over your array using `forEach`:

```js
n = 25;
const obj = {
  1: 10,
  2: 20,
  3: 30,
  4: 40,
  5: 50,
};
arr = Object.entries(obj);
res = {};
arr.forEach((elem,index,array)=>{
if(n>elem[1]){
res.current = {[elem[0]]:elem[1]};
//get index from provided argument
res.next = {[array[index+1][0]]:array[index+1][1]};
}
});
console.log(res);
```

The advantage of `forEach` is that it passes an `index` parameter which you can use to get the next object in the array.